# Dynamic shared memory space for Tcl and C threads

Tags: c, multithreading, tcl

I want to have a dynamic shared memory space between a Tcl and a C thread.

The size of that thread shared memory space is allocated when running `xxx_Init (Tcl_Interp *interp) {...}` procedure but I would like to allocate it with a space depending of a Tcl variable in order to opimize memory use.

Is it possible? If yes, how to do so?

EDIT: Detailled code provided showing what I want to do and my problem.

A pointer to a structure containing shared data will be shared as client data with a procedure called `testCmd` which allocates the memory space size following two Tcl's variables. It is also shared as client data with a newly created thread. The C extension is detailed hereunder **but does not work because the memory space is not shared between threads** and should be defined in the `xxx_Init (Tcl_Interp *interp) {...}` procedure. But if I do so, I can not get Tcl's variables specifying the memory space size to allocate.

```
    #include <tcl.h>

typedef struct dataHandle_ {
    char *data ;
    long p1 ;
    long p2 ;
} dataHandle_T ;

// Thread function
// Test if we can write memory space allocated by 'testCmd0' function
static void startRoutine (ClientData clientData) {
    dataHandle_T *dH = (dataHandle_T *) clientData;
    //test
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("testFile.txt", "w");
    while (1) { 
        int mul=dH->p1*dH->p2;
        if (mul<10) {
            dH->data="A";
        } else {
            dH->data="Large str";
        }
        fprintf(file, "Memory size is %d, word is %s ", mul, dH->data);
    }
    fclose(file);
}


// Test command
// Allocating a new memory space for thread shared memory, depending on 2 Tcl variables values
int testCmd(
    ClientData data,
    Tcl_Interp *interp,
    int objc,
    Tcl_Obj *CONST objv[])
{
    dataHandle_T *dH = (dataHandle_T *)data ;

    // Check the number of arguments
    if (objc != 3) {
        Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "arg arg");
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    long p1, p2, result ;

    if ( Tcl_GetLongFromObj(interp, objv[1], &p1) != TCL_OK)
        return TCL_ERROR ;

    if ( Tcl_GetLongFromObj(interp, objv[2], &p2)  != TCL_OK)
        return TCL_ERROR ;

    // Is a re-allocation needed?
    if (dH->p1 != p1 || dH->p2 != p2) {
        if (dH->data != NULL)
            Tcl_Free(dH->data) ;
        dH->data = Tcl_Alloc(p1 * p2 * sizeof(char)) ;// Or whatever allocation you need
    }

    return TCL_OK ;

}

// Create thread launching startRoutine procedure with a dataHandle_T as argument
createThread_Cmd(
    ClientData cdata,
    Tcl_Interp *interp,
    int objc,
    Tcl_Obj *const objv[])
{

    // Contain the ID of the newly created thread
    Tcl_ThreadId id;    
    // Thread argument
    ClientData limitData;

    // Transfering global var argument to the created thread
    limitData=cdata;

    // Thread creation
    id=0;
    Tcl_CreateThread(&id, startRoutine, limitData, TCL_THREAD_STACK_DEFAULT, TCL_THREAD_NOFLAGS);

    // Return thread ID to tcl prog to allow thread management
    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewIntObj((int) id));
    return TCL_OK;  
}


// Note the casing on the _Init function name
int DLLEXPORT

Test_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp)
{
    // Link with the stubs library to make the extension as portable as possible
    if (Tcl_InitStubs(interp, "8.1", 0) == NULL) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    // Declare which package and version is provided by this C code
    if ( Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "BasicTclExtn", "1.0") != TCL_OK ) {
        return TCL_ERROR ;
    }

    // Allocate the storage for the ClientData
    dataHandle_T *hD = (dataHandle_T *)Tcl_Alloc(sizeof(dataHandle_T));

    // Initialise the new structure
    hD->data = NULL ;
    hD->p1 = -1 ;
    hD->p2 = -1 ;

    // Create a command
    Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "test", testCmd, (ClientData)hD, (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *)NULL);
    Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "createThread", createThread_Cmd, (ClientData)hD, NULL);
    return TCL_OK ;
}
```

When executing the following Tcl's code:

```
load [file join [pwd] libtest[info sharedlibextension]]
test 1 2

set threadId [createThread]
puts "Created thread $threadId"
after 500
# ==Produce an error==
test 4 3
after 500
test 10 20
# =====
exit 1
```

The code's output gives (if the part producing an error is commented or not):

```
$ tclsh test.tcl
Created thread -1227109568
$ tclsh test.tcl
Created thread -1227019456
alloc: invalid block: 0x431abb: 69 2e
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Note that you're going to have to copy data in and out of that space a fair bit; Tcl's value memory management can't directly cope with the constraints of a shared memory block as such.

Comment: So where do PARAMETER1 and PARAMETER2 come from then? Are they defined in the Tcl interpreter?

Comment: Should the line: sharedData* sDataPtr; not be varList* sDataPtr; ?

Comment: Indeed, updated. Sorry for the messy question...

Comment: If PARAMTER1 and PARAMETER2 are just #defined then what's the problem; you know the values.

Comment: I define it myself for the moment, but this program is integrated in a bigger Tcl one which will use different lists sizes, some really big and I don't want, if possible, to edit those parameters or over-or undersize it...

Answer (score 2):

The one parameter you have into your _Init function is Tcl_Interp*.  So with this you should be able to use Tcl_Eval or one of its variants to execute some Tcl code in that interpreter. You should then be able to run a Tcl proc say that returns the value you want and then use Tcl_GetObjResult() to retrieve the value from the Interp.

The following code works for me in my _Init function:

```
int res ;
if ( Tcl_Eval(interp, "set myVal") != TCL_OK)
    return TCL_ERROR ;

if (Tcl_GetIntFromObj(interp,Tcl_GetObjResult(interp), &res) != TCL_OK)
    return TCL_ERROR ;
```

with the following Tcl scrip:

```
set myVal 102
load basicTclExtn.dll
```

The value 102 ends up in the C++ res variable.

Based on the edits and comments I've ended up with the following code which I hope will sort out your problem:

First of all the Tcl C extension

```
typedef struct dataHandle_ {
    char *data ;
    long p1 ;
    long p2 ;
} dataHandle_T ;

// Test command
int testCmd(
    ClientData data,
    Tcl_Interp *interp,
    int objc,
    Tcl_Obj *CONST objv[])
{
    dataHandle_T *dH = (dataHandle_T *)data ;

    // Check the number of arguments
    if (objc != 3) {
        Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "arg arg");
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    long p1, p2, result ;

    if ( Tcl_GetLongFromObj(interp, objv[1], &p1) != TCL_OK)
        return TCL_ERROR ;

    if ( Tcl_GetLongFromObj(interp, objv[2], &p2)  != TCL_OK)
        return TCL_ERROR ;

    // Is a re-allocation needed?
    if (dH->p1 != p1 || dH->p2 != p2) {
        if (dH->data != NULL)
            Tcl_Free(dH->data) ;
        dH->data = Tcl_Alloc(p1 * p2 * sizeof(char)) ;// Or whatever allocation you need
    }

    return TCL_OK ;

}

// Note the casing on the _Init function name
BASICTCLEXTN_API int Basictclextn_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp)
{
    // Link with the stubs library to make the extension as portable as possible
    if (Tcl_InitStubs(interp, "8.1", 0) == NULL) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    // Declare which package and version is provided by this C code
    if ( Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "BasicTclExtn", "1.0") != TCL_OK ) {
        return TCL_ERROR ;
    }

    // Allocate the storage for the ClientData
    dataHandle_T *hD = (dataHandle_T *)Tcl_Alloc(sizeof(dataHandle_T));

    // Initialise the new structure
    hD->data = NULL ;
    hD->p1 = -1 ;
    hD->p2 = -1 ;

    // Create a command
    Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "test", testCmd, (ClientData)hD, (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *)NULL);

    return TCL_OK ;
}
```

And then the Tcl script

```
load basicTclExtn.dll
puts [BasicExtnCmd 10 12]
test 1 2
test 3 4
```

So the memory gets re-allocated each time test gets called based on the values of the first 2 parameters to test.

Comment: Ok, this is a good idea. However, I want the variable name in `Tcl_Eval` to be a parameter and that the memory space size to be reallocated on a particular Tcl command.
If I pass the pointer to the memory space to a C extended function as ClientData, is it possible to modify the memory space it points to and that space to be not freed when exiting function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your 1st question, when do you know what the variable name will be and what to you what it passed to as a parameter? If you pass some ClientData to Tcl_CreateCommand() then that same value is available in the C code that implements the command and is retained until the command is deleted using Tcl_DeleteCommand.  So if the ClientData points to a memory location that points to your allocated space then you can re-allocate the space as you desire without having to change the ClientData - another level of indirection kind of a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Indeed, it works, I already did something like this but the `dH` shared memory space can be shared between threads? I will try it later, but I don't think it will work because the memory space will not be global...

Comment: We've kind of moved away from your original question which is about getting the PARAMETER1/2 data into you C extension.

Comment: Since the beginning and in the subject, I talked about thread dynamic shared memory... But indeed, I don't master the subject and asking the clear question is difficult...

Comment: Question updated. I provided code as I would like to have and the errors I got.